# Information to share with recruiter?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, recruitment, human-resources, united-kingdom

I been looking for a job a 2 months now and been having a lot of calls from recruiter. But lately I been really keeping eye on what sort of questions I am being asked e.g

1. What is your date of birth like year month and day
2. Can you send us your passport copy or home office document stating your current status.
3. Can you send me reference for your history
4. Please give a list of companies you been interviewed with or recruiter name
5. Some recruiter claims to have exclusively to recruiter for xyz company where no one else have the right and other recruiter says whoever he is he is lying.

And many others. I don't know much about them and I am thinking I am leaking Information. Is there any laws to abide by before knowing what they can ask and what can I share?
Some recruiter just block me off after I went for interview or asking a long story about my work history and never contact me. How do I tackle or complain and know my rights to share information.

Comment: For Number 5, the recruiter might also be saying that **you** can only be represented by them to a particular company. This is often a standard part of a recruiting agreement, but would require you to sign and agree to that.

Comment: Regarding your rights, because you are in the UK,  all the information you provide is protected under the Data Protection Act. You have the right to see any data someone holds about you and have it annexed if incorrect. Data should also be kept no longer than necessary.

Comment: @JamesFenwick How can i see my see if someone holds my data and what sort of?

Comment: @Nofel Generally you just have to ask, the legislation may specify a specific wording but in most cases that would not be necessary. You may be charged a small (~£10) fee. There are some exceptions to when someone would have to disclose your information but no reasons that would be on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Some recruiters will try and gain any information that can help them get people into jobs, because that's how their earn their money.

While good for you, in that they will try and do anything they can to get you into a position, they will also help your "competition".

I.e., they will fish from you for open positions at other companies. "Where have you already applied/interviewed?". Answering this question has no positive outcome for you. You already have an "in" at that company, and letting recruiters know there is a position going there only allows them to put other candidates forward and increase your competition for getting that role.

You do however have to ensure that you only apply for a role once, either independently or through a recruiter. So ensure you know everywhere you've been put forward to, and don't allow a recruiter to put you forward to somewhere you've already been in contact with. Some companies won't touch you if they hear from you via multiple means.

Comment: What annoy me the most is telling your story about your previous role and the points mentioned above and they might disappear after having info or arrange a interview, i go there and i never hear from them. It is two loss for me, one is i spend time and energy on telling recruiter about me. 2. I travel for interview spending money on commute and i never hear the feedback from some recruiters.

Answer (score 0):

> What is your date of birth like year month and day

**Yeah**, recruiters generally ask your date of birth for a lot of purposes, the most important one being age calculation.

> Can you send us your passport copy or home office document stating
>   your current status.

**Mostly No**, required for legal purposes. But, not really required before the interview process is done. (Maybe they need it for background checking). So, ask them the purpose before giving the documents to them.

> Can you send me reference for your history

**Yes** Required for past work experience and for background checking, along with the references.

> Some recruiter claims to have exclusively to recruiter for xyz company
>   where no one else have the right and other recruiter says whoever he
>   is he is lying.

The only way you can confirm this would be to check their LinkedIn profile and/or their email address. Genuine recruiters almost always mail from their official email addresses.

So, never leak off your info unless and until you are completely sure that the recruiter is genuine. And I repeat again: **Genuine recruiters almost always mail from their official email addresses.**
And do search for a LinkedIn profile too. Genuine recruiters mostly have a very detailed profile.

Comment: In Europe your age is not something a recruiter should be asking about. There are strong anti discrimination laws.
Also references should only be given once an offer of employment is made. before that you are just filling their database with targets to harass.